# iOS 6: Turn off keyboard shortcuts

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-text

Is there is any way to turn off keyboard shortcuts in iOS 6 for particular textfield/textview?
I want to turn off keyboard shortcut for my app only and not from 'Settings app' of iOS.

I started writing my own text editor to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to turn off keyboard shortcuts on application level (For non jailbroken iOS).
To achieve this I stated with implementation of custom TextView with `Core Text` and `UITextInput` protocol.
Add `@property` for `keyBoardShortCuts`,
Override "`tokenizer`" getter method by following way to turn off shortcuts.

```
- (id <UITextInputTokenizer>)tokenizer {
    if(self.keyBoardShortCuts)
        return _tokenizer;
    else
        return nil;
}
```

If we remove tokenizer, there is be no keyboard shortcuts in custom view, even though shortcut are turned on from iOS setting.

Note: Take care of one thing, as we are not depending on tokenizer, now, in this case, use enumerateSubstringsInRange:range options:NSStringEnumerationByWords/Lines block to find out selection range for word or line.

To try this add above code in [EGOTextView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOTextView) project to turn off default shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

You could try turning off autocorrection for your text field or text view with its `autocorrectionType` property—if the shortcut functionality is included in that (which seems likely), then it should get disabled as well. I’m pretty sure there’s no way to control the shortcut system itself; you might consider filing an [enhancement request](http://bugreport.apple.com) for it.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried already, autocorrectionType will not help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, if you iphone is not jailbroken then you cannot turn it off for particular apps. It is more like a "master setting" that if changed, change applies to everything within iOS.

If it jailbroken, i know there are utility apps you can download that allow you to tweak the OS in that fashion...

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I want it for non jailbroken iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Settings > General > Shortcuts. There are ready-made ones and any that you may have set up. They apply across all your iOS devices including your desktop Mac.